# IBM Watson Assistant - Webhook Uncaught Error when saving URL

Tags: webhooks, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

**Problem:**
Webhook URLs are not saved, which breakes the entire webhook functionality.

**Reproduction:**
When creating a new dialog skill in the classic experience, the following error is printed to console once I've entered a webhook URL in the respective options field.

```
DialogSkillOptions.jsx:210 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
at DialogSkillOptions.jsx:210:42
at s (bluemix-analytics.min.js:44:30656)
at Generator._invoke (bluemix-analytics.min.js:44:30409)
at Generator.next (bluemix-analytics.min.js:44:31019)
at C (app.46eb13fc2099d97e0fdd.js:1:3312231)
at i (app.46eb13fc2099d97e0fdd.js:1:3312434)
```

If one then tries again to change the URL, no error is thrown. However, the URL is still not saved correctly (trying to use it in a dialog node displays the "webhook URL missing" warning box).

For the URL I used different examples, including the one from documentation.

Comment: What type of browser? Any scripting plugins? Have you configured the webhook in the dialog settings or is this for a step?

Comment: @data_henrik I tried to enter it in the dialog settings on both chrome and firefox with all plugins disabled/incognito mode.